# Python Processing time 30+ mins in VSCODE

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, scikit-learn, nltk

I'm super new to programming so please be patient and keep it simple because I just started last week learning python. I'm willing to post anything you need for more info but remember, I'm a n00b.

My problem:

I'm using MACOSX Sierra with Visual Studio Code with python 2.7 and running into YUGE data processing times (i.e. 5+ minutes, closer to 10+ minutes, and on this particular code 30+ minutes)

Any suggestions? i haven't really been able to find too much on a solution anywhere online.

My CPU in activity monitor is at like a steady 98% when running these processes and I don't know if this is normal or what to do to speed things up.

caveat:

In simple coding my processing time isn't too bad, but it seems when algorithms are introduced, things bog way down and it's frustrating.

Below is the coding I'm using that seems to run fine except with insane processing times with the output included at the end:

```
    import nltk
    import random
    from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
    from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
    import pickle

    from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB, GaussianNB, BernoulliNB
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, SGDClassifier
    from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC, NuSVC

    from nltk.classify import ClassifierI
    from statistics import mode


    class VoteClassifier(ClassifierI):
        def __init__(self, *classifiers):
            self._classifiers = classifiers

        def classify(self, features):
            votes = []
            for c in self._classifiers:
                v = c.classify(features)
                votes.append(v)
            return mode(votes)

        def confidence(self, features):
            votes = []
            for c in self._classifiers:
                v = c.classify(features)
                votes.append(v)

            choice_votes = votes.count(mode(votes))
            conf = choice_votes / len(votes)
            return conf



    documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
                for category in movie_reviews.categories()
                for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]

    random.shuffle(documents)

    all_words = []
    for w in movie_reviews.words():
        all_words.append(w.lower())

    all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)

    word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]

    def find_features(document):
        words = set(document)
        features = {}
        for w in word_features:
            features[w] = (w in words)

        return features

    # print((find_features(movie_reviews.words('neg/cv000_29416.txt'))))

    featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents]

    training_set = featuresets[:1900]
    testing_set = featuresets[:1900:]

    # classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)

    classifier_f = open("naivebayes.pickle", "rb")
    classifier = pickle.load(classifier_f)
    classifier_f.close()

    print("Original Naive Bayes Algo accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, testing_set))*100)
    classifier.show_most_informative_features(15)

    # save_classifier = open("naivebayes.pickle", "wb")
    # pickle.dump(classifier, save_classifier)
    # save_classifier.close()

    MNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB())
    MNB_classifier.train(training_set)
    print("MNB_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(MNB_classifier, testing_set))*100)

    # GaussianNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(GaussianNB())
    # GaussianNB_classifier.train(training_set)
    # print("GaussianNB_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(GaussianNB_classifier, testing_set))*100)

    BernoulliNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(BernoulliNB())
    BernoulliNB_classifier.train(training_set)
    print("BernoulliNB_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(BernoulliNB_classifier, testing_set))*100)

    LogisticRegression_classifier = SklearnClassifier(LogisticRegression())
    LogisticRegression_classifier.train(training_set)
    print("LogisticRegression_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(LogisticRegression_classifier, testing_set))*100)

    SGDClassifier_classifier = SklearnClassifier(SGDClassifier())
    SGDClassifier_classifier.train(training_set)
    print("SGDClassifier_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(SGDClassifier_classifier, testing_set))*100)

    # SVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(SVC())
    # SVC_classifier.train(training_set)
    # print("SVC_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(SVC_classifier, testing_set))*100)

    LinearSVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())
    LinearSVC_classifier.train(training_set)
    print("LinearSVC_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(LinearSVC_classifier, testing_set))*100)

    NuSVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(NuSVC())
    NuSVC_classifier.train(training_set)
    print("NuSVC_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(NuSVC_classifier, testing_set))*100)

    voted_classifier = VoteClassifier(classifier, MNB_classifier, BernoulliNB_classifier, LogisticRegression_classifier, SGDClassifier_classifier, LinearSVC_classifier, NuSVC_classifier)

    print("voted_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(voted_classifier, testing_set))*100)

    print("Classication:", voted_classifier.classify(testing_set[0][0]), "Confidence %:", voted_classifier.confidence(testing_set[0][0])*100)

    print("Classication:", voted_classifier.classify(testing_set[1][0]), "Confidence %:", voted_classifier.confidence(testing_set[1][0])*100)
    print("Classication:", voted_classifier.classify(testing_set[2][0]), "Confidence %:", voted_classifier.confidence(testing_set[2][0])*100)
    print("Classication:", voted_classifier.classify(testing_set[3][0]), "Confidence %:", voted_classifier.confidence(testing_set[3][0])*100)
    print("Classication:", voted_classifier.classify(testing_set[4][0]), "Confidence %:", voted_classifier.confidence(testing_set[4][0])*100)
    print("Classication:", voted_classifier.classify(testing_set[5][0]), "Confidence %:", voted_classifier.confidence(testing_set[5][0])*100)
```

```
    ('Original Naive Bayes Algo accuracy percent:', 87.31578947368422)
    Most Informative Features
                  insulting = True              neg : pos    =     11.0 : 1.0
                       sans = True              neg : pos    =      9.0 : 1.0
               refreshingly = True              pos : neg    =      8.4 : 1.0
                    wasting = True              neg : pos    =      8.3 : 1.0
                 mediocrity = True              neg : pos    =      7.7 : 1.0
                  dismissed = True              pos : neg    =      7.0 : 1.0
                    customs = True              pos : neg    =      6.3 : 1.0
                     fabric = True              pos : neg    =      6.3 : 1.0
                overwhelmed = True              pos : neg    =      6.3 : 1.0
                bruckheimer = True              neg : pos    =      6.3 : 1.0
                      wires = True              neg : pos    =      6.3 : 1.0
                  uplifting = True              pos : neg    =      6.2 : 1.0
                        ugh = True              neg : pos    =      5.8 : 1.0
                     stinks = True              neg : pos    =      5.8 : 1.0
                       lang = True              pos : neg    =      5.7 : 1.0
    ('MNB_classifier accuracy percent:', 89.21052631578948)
    ('BernoulliNB_classifier accuracy percent:', 86.42105263157895)
    ('LogisticRegression_classifier accuracy percent:', 94.47368421052632)
    ('SGDClassifier_classifier accuracy percent:', 85.73684210526315)
    ('LinearSVC_classifier accuracy percent:', 99.52631578947368)
    ('NuSVC_classifier accuracy percent:', 91.52631578947368)
    ('voted_classifier accuracy percent:', 93.36842105263158)
    ('Classication:', u'pos', 'Confidence %:', 100)
    ('Classication:', u'pos', 'Confidence %:', 0)
    ('Classication:', u'neg', 'Confidence %:', 0)
    ('Classication:', u'neg', 'Confidence %:', 100)
    ('Classication:', u'neg', 'Confidence %:', 100)
    ('Classication:', u'neg', 'Confidence %:', 100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a problem. The movie review corpus is not that large, but training a classifier takes a long time... and you train seven of them, with three thousand features. If you start using larger datasets, don't be surprised if it takes all night to train *one* classifier.

I suggest you separate the training script from the testing script (you'll need to pickle all your trained models), and/or print out messages with timestamps at appropriate times to see which of your classifiers are eating up your time. (Also: Consider removing common "stopwords" like "the", "a", ".", etc. from your list of features.)

Comment: hey, thank you so much i really appreciate you getting back to me.

Comment: sorry, i didnt mean to press enter. so, im watching a sentdex tutorial with this exact coding and it seems as if he is getting the output returned in 1 minute or 2 minutes absolute max time. thank you so much, i've just been having problems and didn't know if it was just me or what since i'm brand new.

Comment: You are welcome. Learn how to time and "profile" your code, so you can determine in detail where your runtime is getting soaked up. Training a classifier is slow, but there are tons of things you can do that'll make it _much_ slower.

Comment: thanks so much for your help and insight. I'm going to take your advice and do some follow up research on how to optimize my workflow for minimum processing time with maximum results possible